# what is logic behind multiplication in probability

Tags: math, probability, addition

suppose two coins are tossed find the probability of getting two heads
so probability of getting one head is 1/2 and probability of getting
another head is 1/2 so we multiply 1/2*1/2 so my question is why we multiply

Comment: I think this question is better asked on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wrong place to ask, but FWIW always go back to `n/N` where `n` is the number of desired outcomes and `N` the number of possible outcomes. If you do the maths right in case of independent events you'll end up with the multiplication formula.

Comment: It is possible to derive the usual laws of probability from more fundamental considerations about generalizing logic under uncertainty. This approach is the so-called logical Bayesian interpretation of probability; the short article "Probability, Frequency, and Reasonable Expectation" by R.T. Cox (J. American Physics, vol 14, no 1, 1946) is a pleasant introduction. A web search will find the article. See also the book by E.T. Jaynes, "Probability Theory: The Logic of Science" which repeats and extends Cox's argument.